# java - MavenError: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, java-17

I recently upgraded a Spring 2.X project to a 3.2.2 as well as upgraded from JDK 8 to JDK 17 since I believe this is the minimum requirement for Spring 3.
The project runs in the IDE environment (Spring Tool Suite 4) but when I try to compile using `mvn package war:war` in the cmd it fails.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aca</groupId>
    <artifactId>academico</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>academico</name>
    <description>Academico en spring</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>                       
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>           
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>18.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<!--            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
<!--            <version>3.0.0</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
<!--            <version>3.0.1</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
<!--            <version>6.0.0</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
           <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
<!--           <version>12.4.0.jre8</version>-->
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.11</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons.ssl</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-ssl</artifactId> 
             <version>0.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>                   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kenglxn.qrgen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
           
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220320</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.10.1</version>-->
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>                        
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <release>17</release>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is the error stack trace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitSelect(TreeTranslator.java:391)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.visitSelect(LambdaToMethod.java:563)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitSelect(TreeTranslator.java:391)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.visitSelect(LambdaToMethod.java:563)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitSelect(TreeTranslator.java:391)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.visitSelect(LambdaToMethod.java:563)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitSelect(TreeTranslator.java:391)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.visitSelect(LambdaToMethod.java:563)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2450)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitTypeCast(TreeTranslator.java:350)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCTypeCast.accept(JCTree.java:2185)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:267)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.LambdaToMethod.translate(LambdaToMethod.java:260)

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.389 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-12T12:17:17-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project academico: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
```

And also here is my mvn -v output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KviG6.png)

I would appreciate the help since I been looking for hours and I can't seem to figure out a solution.

I have tried adding multiple configurations of the maven-compiler-plugin as well as manually changing the maven versions with no success.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<build>
    <plugins>                        
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
               <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    <arg>-Werror</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

add

```
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    <arg>-Werror</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
```

or like this

```
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Werror</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        </args>
```

to your Plugin in pom

Comment: Tried this and now it is leading me to different files that all seem to have some form of java.lang.String casting and this seems to be happening throughout the project. Could it actually be that those castings are causing a compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

Ojdbc8 -> Oracle JDBC Driver compatible with JDK8, JDK11, JDK12, JDK13, JDK14 and JDK15
Try with : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc11

According to documentation: https://www.oracle.com/pl/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Comment: This is something I definitely needed to change and hadn't notice before, unfortunately this didn't solve the error. I get the same compilation error even after I upgraded to ojdbc11